# Custom margin for footnote area

Tags: footnotes, margins, footmisc

From searching this forum, I can see how to indent footnotes that are in paragraph format. However, I didn't see an example of what I'd like to do: I'd like to essentially set a custom left margin for the entire footnote area.

I'm setting my paragraphs with a hanging indent, and I'd like to restrict the footnote area to align with the left and right sides of the main text block, as shown below. Instead of the footnotes spanning the area they currently span, I'd like them to just span the area covered by the red arrow.
[image: Example image]

Here is the sample code that generates the output shown above:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[para*,ruled,perpage]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,asymmetric]{geometry}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]
\geometry{includehead,nofoot,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=0.75in,right=1in,marginparwidth=3em,marginparsep=0ex}

\begin{document}

\par\hangpara{0.25in}{1}\lipsum[1]
\par\hangpara{0.25in}{1}\lipsum[2]
\par\hangpara{0.25in}{1}\footnoteA{This is a fun footnote for sure.}Nam dui ligula, \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}non justo. Nam lacus \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}libero, pretium
at, lobortis \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}vitae, ultricies et, tellus. \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}Donec aliquet, tortor
sed \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote, don't you think?}accumsan bibendum, erat ligula \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}aliquet magna, vitae ornare
\footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}odio metus a mi. \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}Morbi ac orci et nisl \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}ut massa. Cras \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}nec ante. \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}Pellentesque a nulla.
Cum sociis \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}natoque penatibus et\footnoteA{This is a fun footnote} magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}ridiculus mus. Aliquam \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote...not!}tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}vestibulum turpis. \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}Pellentesque cursus \footnoteA{This is a fun footnote}luctus
mauris.
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line right above the DeclareNewFootnote line in the code from my original post:

```
\SetFootnoteHook{\leftskip0.25in}
```

and it produced these results:

[image]

However, if anyone knows of a more correct/elegant solution, I would still appreciate the feedback.